# Get joined rows as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following tables:

Table **person**:

```
personid     name  
-----------------
1            bob
2            jackson
3            madison
```

Table **personlink**

```
linkid  personid  type       mailid
-----------------------------------
1       1         business   1
2       1         private    2
3       2         business   3
```

Table **mail**

```
mailid  email
-----------------------------------
1       bob@business.com
2       bob@private.com
3       jackson@business.com
```

I would like the result of my SQL query to be like this:

```
personid     name          privatemail      businessmail
--------------------------------------------------------
1            bob           bob@private.com  bob@business.com
2            jackson       [null]           jackson@business.com
3            madison       [null]           [null]
```

Maybe there is an easier way but I think I need to use dynamic SQL with pivot which I cannot get to work.

Comment: How many different types of email do you have?

Comment: Have a look at the `PIVOT` operator, or a Cross Tab; there are literally 100's of examples on SO of these. If you failed to implement these methods, then show us those attempts and explain why they didn't work.

Comment: Can be up to four

Comment: Ok i got it. The problem was that struggled because of the aggregate function in pivot. But you can just use max

Answer (score 1):

A pivot is a possibility. But if you have only a few types of E-mails you could use **subselects**. Verify performance (execution plan) if you have lots of records. Regardless of whether any indexes are present, I don't think is worse than any other approach though.

```
SELECT personid, [name],
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
    mail.email FROM mail
    INNER JOIN personlink
    ON mail.mailid = personlink.mailid
    WHERE personlink.[type] = 'private'
    AND personlink.personid = person.personid
) AS privatemail,

(
SELECT TOP 1 
    mail.email FROM mail
    INNER JOIN personlink
    ON mail.mailid = personlink.mailid
    WHERE personlink.[type] = 'business'
    AND personlink.personid = person.personid
) AS businessmail

FROM person;
```

[Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4cf3f42aedcdab9494f090c2f1a544ec) to DBfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f920c00ad82f41802c978997e6bd5034)

```
SELECT P.personid,P.name,
MAX(CASE WHEN pl.type = 'private' THEN M.email END) privatemail,      
MAX(CASE WHEN pl.type = 'business' THEN M.email END) businessmail
-- You can add more condition here based on Email Type
FROM Person P 
LEFT JOIN personlink PL ON P.personid = pl.personid
LEFT JOIN mail M ON pl.mailid = M.mailid
GROUP BY P.personid,P.name
```